# Receiving error "WCF request failed" for Exchange Server 2013

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013

I am a newbie in Exchange 2013 having it installed with CU19 for a domain/forest sl.org in my test environment. This forest also contains a domain called fj.net.

Now when sending within sl.org everythings works well.

However when trying to add a user from fj.net and providing him/her an email address it fails. Eventlog on Exchange 2013 is showing the following:

> Process w3wp.exe (ECP) (PID=6744). WCF request (GetServerFromDomainDN DC=fj,DC=net) to the Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server (TopologyClientTcpEndpoint (localhost)) failed. Make sure that the service is running. In addition, make sure that the network ports that are used by Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service are not blocked by a firewall. The WCF call was retried 3 time(s). Error Details 
>    No suitable domain controller was found in domain 'fj.net'. Errors:
>
> at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.RemoteDomainServerDiscovery.d__5.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.Extensions.TaskFactoryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3`1.b__1(Task unusedAntecedentTask)

What is the reason for this? Do I have to install a separate Exchange Server for fj.net?

Please note: All Windows Firewalls are set to 'off' (for testing purposes); this cannot be the reason so far.

Comment: I don't think you can have two different namespaces in the same forest.  Do you mean that in Active Directory you have a root forest named sl.org and then a child domain of sl.org named fj.net?  Or do you mean that you have two MX records for sl.org and fj.net but that your Active Directory that you have Exchange installed into has some other FQDN?

Comment: I do have a forest named sl.org and then a child domain of sl.org named fj.net. Interestingly the users with the UPN part of fj.net show up in Exchange, but when choosing them the above mentioned error can be seen.